# Numanckaret and Leda We abandoned me. Can I come back later and kill them?

Tags: x4-foundations

Numanckaret and Leda We abandoned me at the Sanctuary of Darkness jump gate when a small number of Kha'ak fighters attacked, despite having two capital ships and numerous medium/small ships. My ship was destroyed and I flew half an hour in my spacesuit to the Guppy, barely making it aboard before my O2 ran out.

[image: At least they didn't leave the system]

Hailing their ships they would only talk to me about where to find a shipyard, and offered no aid.

Can I build up a navy, come back, and exterminate these cowards, or do they have plot armour?